# Identify the source MidiDevice for a MIDI package on Android

Tags: android, midi

**Context:**

Using the standard [Android MIDI API for Android 6+](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html), there's a pretty clear way to receive MIDI messages from other MIDI devices, including Virtual ones a.k.a. other apps in the `MidiReceiver#onSend()` method.

Since the App accepts MIDI Clock messages, it's not desired for the App to receive multiple clocks, thus the user would need to accept a new incoming MIDI message from a MidiDevice that didn't communicate with the App before.

It's true that you can know when the status of any device changes regarding how many ports are open. But the information you receive seems rather lacking for me to fully understand who is connected to this App and what is being received from each one of the other MidiDevices:

- The [MidiDeviceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDeviceInfo.html) tells you the id, type, PortInfo[] and other stuff.
- The [PortInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDeviceInfo.PortInfo.html) has no information regarding if it's open or not.
- The [MidiDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDevice.html) does tell you the total input and output ports that are open, but not with which other MidiDevice they're connected to.

**Question:**

How could I filter through incoming MIDI messages by sender, besides looking into the MIDI channel?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
The identity of the sender is not part of the message information.

Comment: Hi @CL thanks for your answer. I'm afraid you speak the crude truth there, would you say there's also no way to know which port from my app gets disconnected on `deviceStatusChanged()`?